# Sourcetree git push remote: Repository not found

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I cloned a repo from the CLI using `git clone https://github.com/**.git`

Then I added this repo to **Sourcetree**, committed some changes and tried to push, but is presented with:

`remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/**.git/' not found`

However, `git push` worked properly in the CLI.

I'm using Github with 2FA, but am sure I entered the token instead of my Github's password.

Have checked https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/ but since it works fine with the CLI, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the token's permission to allow private repos.
Its working now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did to fix this? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: Haven't used sourcetree in a while. IIRC, you should provide your personal access token and make sure it has the right permissions in https://github.com/settings/tokens. I believe I was missing the private repos permission then.